# How to extend JqPlot class and add my own prototype functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, jqplot

I want to extend the Jqplot class and add more functions to it.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var myFunc = new JqPlot();

myFunc.prototype.sayhello = function(){
   alert("hi");
}

or

var myFunc = new $.JqPlot();

myFunc.prototype.sayhello = function(){
   alert("hi");
}
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if jqplot is a function that allows you to create normal objects but you could try this:

```
var MyJPlot=function(){
 JqPlot.call(this);
};
MyJPlot.prototype=new JqPlot();
MyJPlot.prototype.somethingNew=function(){
  console.log("something new");
}

var mp=new MyJPlot();
...
```

Basic explanation about prototype in JavaScript: [Prototypical inheritance - writing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711)

If you'd like something more advanced you can have a look at [goog.base and goog.inherits](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_base.js.html)

Comment: No this didn't work.
basically i want to override the fillbetweenline functionality of JqPlot.

Comment: `MytJPlot.prototype.fillbetweenline=function(){console.log("overridden");}`